Three inellipses in a triangle - concurrent lines
A few years ago, when I was playing around with GeoGebra, I found the following result experimentally, yet I couldn't prove it.

Proposition
In a triangle $ABC$ with six conconic points $\{B_A, C_A\}\in\overline{BC}$, $\{C_B, A_B\}\in\overline{CA}$, $\{A_C, B_C\}\in\overline{AB}$, let $\mathcal{E}_A$ be the inellipse tangent to $\overline{CA}$ at $A_B$, tangent to $\overline{AB}$ at $A_C$. Similarly, let $\mathcal{E}_B$ be the inellipse tangent to $\overline{AB}$ at $B_C$, tangent to $\overline{BC}$ at $B_A$, let $\mathcal{E}_C$ be the inellipse tangent to $\overline{BC}$ at $C_A$, tangent to $\overline{CA}$ at $C_B$. As shown in the figure, $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$, $C_2$ are six of the twelve intersection points of the three inellipses $\mathcal{E}_A$, $\mathcal{E}_B$, $\mathcal{E}_C$. Then, the three lines $AA_1$, $BB_1$, $CC_1$ are concurrent. Similarly, $AA_2$, $BB_2$, $CC_2$ are concurrent.

The problem is, I want to formulate this proposition without the aid of figures, but I can't figure out how to define these intersections $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$, $A_2$, $B_2$, $C_2$ properly. Two conics have four intersections, and in this case we have to choose the right one. How do we define the appropriate intersection points of the three ellipses so that the above proposition can hold?
In the figure below, the following three lines are also concurrent.

$AA_1$, $BB_4$, $CC_3$
$AA_2$, $BB_3$, $CC_4$
$AA_3$, $BB_1$, $CC_4$
$AA_3$, $BB_4$, $CC_2$
$AA_4$, $BB_3$, $CC_1$
$AA_4$, $BB_2$, $CC_3$

where $$\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}:=\mathcal{E}_B\cap\mathcal{E}_C,$$
$$\{B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4\}:=\mathcal{E}_C\cap\mathcal{E}_A,$$
$$\{C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4\}:=\mathcal{E}_A\cap\mathcal{E}_B.$$

However, $AA_1$, $BB_2$, $CC_3$ are clearly not concurrent, so we have to define these intersections carefully, but how?
A projective, algebraic or analytic approach is welcome.

One way to proceed is to solve the problem algebraically and see if the algebra provides a "reasonable" way to distinguish the points that work from those that don't.

Start with $\triangle ABC$ and conconic points $A_B$, $B_C$, $C_A$, $A_C$, $B_A$, $C_B$, where $P_Q$ is on a side through vertex $P$ and opposite vertex $Q$.

Assign the following barycentric coordinates:
$$\begin{align}
  B_A=\;&\; 0:b_A^2:1 \qquad
& C_B=\;&\;  1:0:c_B^2 \qquad
& A_C=\;&\; a_C^2:1:0 \\ 
  C_A=\;&\; 0:1:c_A^2 \qquad
& A_B=\;&\; a_B^2:0:1 \qquad
& B_C=\;&\; 1:b_C^2:0
\end{align} \tag1$$
where we'll take un-squared parameters $a_B$, $b_C$, etc, to be non-negative. (The squared parameters are notationally convenient for equations $(4)$, $(5)$, $(6)$ (a bit less-so for $(3)$). Moreover, non-negative barycentric coordinates naturally constrain points $A_B$, $B_C$, etc, to the non-extended sides of the triangle; this is appropriate for a discussion of inellipses.)
The conconic property corresponds to the equality
$$a_B\,b_C\,c_A \;=\; a_C\,b_A\,c_B \tag2$$
One can show that the barycentric equations for the prescribed inellipses are
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}_A:&\quad 
  u^2 \,\phantom{a_A^4} 
+ v^2 \,a_C^4 
+ w^2 \,a_B^4
- 2 vw\,a_B^2 a_C^2 
- 2 wu\,a_B^2 \phantom{a_A^2}
- 2 uv\,a_C^2\phantom{a_A^2} = 0 \\[4pt]
\mathcal{E}_B:&\quad
  u^2\,b_C^4 + v^2\,\phantom{b_B^4} + w^2\,b_A^4 \,
- 2 vw\,b_A^2\phantom{b_B^2} 
- 2 wu\,b_C^2 b_A^2 - 2 uv\,b_C^2\phantom{b_B^2}\,= 0  \\[4pt]
\mathcal{E}_C:&\quad
  u^2\,c_B^4
+ v^2\,c_A^4
+ w^2\,\phantom{b_C^4}\,\,
- 2vw\,c_A^2\phantom{b_C^2} 
- 2wu\,c_B^2\phantom{b_C^2}
- 2uv\,c_A^2 c_B^2 \,\,= 0  
\end{align} \tag3$$
The four points in the intersection of $\mathcal{E}_B$ and $\mathcal{E}_C$ have barycentric coordinates of this surprisingly-compact form:
$$A^{st}:\quad 
\left(1 - st\,b_A\,c_A\right)^2 \;:\; 
\left(b_C + s\,b_A\,c_B\right)^2 \;:\; 
\left(c_B + t\,b_C\,c_A\right)^2 \tag4$$
where $s$ and $t$ are independently chosen signs (ie, elements of $\{+1,-1\}$), accounting for four instances. We suppress the "$1$"s in identifying an individual point: $A^{++}$, $A^{--}$, $A^{+-}$, $A^{-+}$. (The figure uses subscripts, for GeoGebra-related reasons.) Likewise, we have $\mathcal{E}_C\cap\mathcal{E}_A$ and $\mathcal{E}_A\cap\mathcal{E}_B$ given by
$$\begin{align}
B^{st}:& \quad (a_C + t\,a_B\,c_A\,)^2 \;:\; (1 - st\,a_B\,c_B\,)^2 \;:\; (c_A + s\,a_C\,c_B)^2 \\[4pt]
C^{st}:& \quad (a_B + s\,a_C\,b_A)^2 \;:\; (b_A + t\,a_B\,b_C)^2 \;:\; (1 - st\,a_C\,b_C)^2
\end{align} \tag5$$
Now, here's the kicker:

The concurrence property holds for (and only for) those points where $s=t$.

(This allows us ot avoid visual clutter in the figure by omitting the labels on the mixed-sign points of intersection.)
That is, lines $AA^{++}$, $BB^{++}$, $CC^{++}$ concur at a point $P^{+}$; while $AA^{--}$, $BB^{--}$, $CC^{--}$ concur at a point $P^{-}$. (The new points are denoted $P_{+}$ and $P_{-}$ in the figure). The barycentric coordinates of these points are
$$P^{\pm}:\quad \frac{\;b_A^2 + c_A^2 + \dfrac{m^2}{
 b_C^2\,c_B^2}\;}{(m\pm b_A\,c_A)^2} \;:\; 
\frac{c_B^2 + a_B^2 + \dfrac{m^2}{c_A^2\,a_C^2}}{(m\pm c_B\,a_B)^2} \;:\; 
\frac{a_C^2 + b_C^2 + \dfrac{m^2}{a_B^2\,b_A^2}}{(m\pm a_C b_C)^2}
\tag{6}$$
where $m \,:=\,a_B\,b_C\,c_A\,=\,a_C\,b_A\,c_B$.

So, the algebra does indeed provide a (fairly) reasonable way to distinguish the points that satisfy the proposition. It's not (yet?) clear to me how the sign differences might translate to some qualitative property of the geometric configuration. I'll leave further pondering on that matter to the reader.
